# Modal Dialog and Form Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that contains some fields and a recaptcha box.

I have hidden the recaptcha box. The user clicks "create profile" and a modal dialog pops up with the recaptcha box. All fine.

But, how do I submit that information? I am using Javascript to create the recaptcha HTML in the modal. I have a button called "Create Profile" that has this code attatched to the onclick:

```
$("#form").submit()
```

The form data gets submitted to the create.php page, but the recaptcha info does not. Do I have to manually pass this information via the post request to create.php?

Without the modal dialog it works fine. I can't understand what's going on.

Any ideas?

The site is www.presslike.net

Comment: Is the modal dialog HTML attached within the form?  If not, your recaptcha is probably not actually in the form.  We'd need to see the HTML and Javascript to be sure.

Comment: The site is at www.presslike.net

Answer (score 1):

Just like ryley said. The modial dialog's HTML is not located between the  tags.   You have two choices

1. Move the modal dialog inside the form
2. Post the data from the form and the Modal using javascript